# Find argument list for an installation exe

Tags: powershell, exe, silent-installer

I am a complete Noob on Windows and, for the first time of my life, I have to make a **Powershell** script to install various services on a server. From what I understood, **silent installations** are made this way:

```
Start-Process "C:\Path\To\some_installer.exe" -ArgumentList "/some /argument" -Wait -PassThru
```

But I cant figure a way to **identify what the arguments should be** for this given `.exe`. On Linux, I would launch the installer and answer to the prompts one by one to know what the arguments are supposed to be. Then:

```sh
(echo arg1; echo arg2) | my command
```

But since `Start-Process` does not display a similar behavior (or I am not using it properly), I am lost. I tried the `-RedirectStandardOutput` but getting nothing in the output file. How do you identify the argument list to provide?

Comment: You can use `Get-Help -Command Start-Process`. That shows you example on how to use the command, etc.

Comment: `NamedParameterNotFound`

Comment: It varies with the exe.  You can try to google "whatever silent install".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Linux, Windows has many package installation tools. The difference is that the Windows installers are mostly designed for GUI. So there is no standard for CLI. For each installation, you need to check for the installer.

If it's an MSI file, you can use the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/standard-installer-command-line-options). If it's an executable, you need to check for the installer. Many software use common installation wizards, but many of them use custom ones.

If you want to use it like Linux, you can use [scoop](https://scoop.sh) or [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org). You can have a local repository in your network then share. Or just use internet. Then you can have silent installation by default.

Comment: I like chocolatey but, unfortunately, what I have to install does not exist on this repo

Comment: I wish I could help you. If you go on with chocolatey, you can try to create a package for yourself or hope someone else do it. That's a hard matter for you and I wouldn't go that way if I don't have to. Still, you can check for each installer for silent install options.

Comment: Thank you @zar3bski